# Layered Navigation Slow Down Our Website. Should I Upgrade Hosting Plan

Tags: magento2

Our website is built in Magento 2.1.7, and recently enabled a Layered Navigation plugin. It it a very good feature for customers and we all like it except the page loading speed.

The obvious difference we can feel is the number of cached pages right now is much less than before. For example, when you open one category page, the speed is extremely slow, and then if you open it on another device, it is as fast as normal. In other words, it seems that the cache memory cannot cover all our frequently visisted pages.

I have been working on it by setting up more attribute sets to eliminate useless attributes in products, and reducing filterable attributes, but we are still not pleased with the performance.

My questions are:

1. Is there any other way I can improve it by settings or coding?
2. If I upgrade the hosting plan, which aspect is more important?
   Now we are using build-in cache, a server with 24GB RAM shared by 13 stores. Next plan is 24GB shared by 4, plus 250GB CDN. Or I just need to upgrade to a varnish cache?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, the slowness is caused by the complexity of MySQL queries. (The layered navigation adds more joins on the eav tables).

Because of this reason, I believe that Varnish won't help here (since it will still need to cache every page of the layered navigation on the first visit).

From reading [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/101090/more-ram-or-more-cores-for-a-mysql-database-server), it seems that more RAM should help (so the next plan that you've mentioned might help).

Another thing that might help (depending on the Layered Navigation implementation) is to try to [enable the flat catalog](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/catalog-flat.html). This should create an entry in the index table for each product, possibly reducing the number of joins that layered navigation uses.

Comment: Another good advice that I got from a colleague that is probably the simplest and the cheapest, is simply to heat up the cache after each cache flush. That is, just create a script that goes to all possible URLs of the layered navigation, and run it every time after the cache flush.